# Subject + combined with (make or makes ?)

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

Which of the following sentences is correct? (make or makes)

"This background combined with my writing skills and presentation skills make me..."

OR

"This background combined with my writing skills and presentation skills makeS me..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main subject is "background", which "make" should agree with, so it should be "makes".

The whole phrase "combined with....skills" is only a modifier.